# Output a field with PHP

Tags: 7, views

I have the *content:path* field and I want to output the containing data with a global PHP field.

it shows me this, but the output with `print $row->path` gives out a number only and not the content path.

> **Available variables**
>
> ```
> $row->path: Inhalt: Pfad
> ```

I tried `print_r($data)` to look for the correct output information, but I did not find anything about the field.

Is there any solution to get this field's data with PHP?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, views PhP doesn't always get the processed field and only gives you the `nid` instead. You have to use `$data` as you tried *(by the way, easier is to `dpm($data)` than `print_r`)*.

if it doesn't give you any info on what you're looking for, you can simply obtain your content:path by using [drupal_lookup_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7) :

```
$path = drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'node/' . $data->nid);
```